# Specify Application Health Extension for healthProbe property in JSON ARM deployment template

Tags: json, azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy an Azure virtual machine scale set (VMSS) using an ARM deployment template. I want to enable automatic OS image upgrades so I set `enableAutomaticUpgrades: true`. The problem is, when I go to deploy the resource I get a validation error that says "Automatic OS upgrade is not supported for this virtual machine scale set because a health probe or health extension was not specified" and the deployment fails. I want to use the [Application Health Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-health-extension?tabs=rest-api), but for the life of me I can't find in the documentation how to specify the Application Health Extension as the healthProbe *in the template*. I know how to do it manually after the resource is created, and I know I can [use a load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-upgrade) as the value like below

```
"networkProfile": {
    "healthProbe" : {
        "id": "[concat(variables('lbId'), '/probes/', variables('sshProbeName'))]"
    },
    "networkInterfaceConfigurations":
    ...
}
```

but I would prefer not to use a load balancer because in my scenario I have no use for one. I have packaged the application health extension as a resource in the template with the following name:

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/HealthRepairExtension')]"
```

and I have tried entering healthProbe.id a number of different ways, including the following

```
"id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/extensions', concat(parameters('vmName'), '/HealthRepairExtension'))]"
```

```
"id": "[extensionResourceId(resourceGroup().Id, 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/extensions', concat(parameters('vmName'), '/HealthRepairExtension'))]"
```

And even tried this

```
"id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', variables('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', variables('resourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/', parameters('vmName'), '/extensions/', parameters('vmName'), '/HealthRepairExtension')]"
```

But nothing works. Every time I get a validation error, sometimes about "Unable to process template language expressions". I don't understand why it's so complicated to specify the only other option besides a load balancer.